# Is there a programmatic way to determine whether a PDF's text is extractable using Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I just spent 45 minutes trying to figure out why pyPdf's

```
PageObject.getPage(x).extractText())
```

wasn't extracting anything.  I finally fed it a different PDF and it worked fine, leading me to conclude that the original PDF has some sort of (non-password) protection on it.  Confirming in Adobe Reader, "page extraction: not allowed."

How, if at all, could I have programmatically determined that this protection was present?

Comment: maybe the first file was corrupt?

Comment: How about you don't try to check for the protection itself, but rather for its results? If you want to check if you can extract text, then try to extract the text. If it works, great, if it doesn't (for whatever reason), you cannot use it and should throw some sort of error.

Comment: @Carsten thanks for the suggestion; I guess I could check to see if the list I assigned to the output of extractText() is empty, but otherwise there is no error.  I can imagine a scenario where that list being blank could mean something other than that there was a problem extracting. (a blank page, for example)

Comment: clarifying the protections on the input PDF: "page extraction" is set to "not allowed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do what you are looking for.

```
x = PageObject.getPage(x).extractText())
if (x == ""): #Or whatever exactly you get when it fails.
   raise ValueError("The PDF file can not be imported")
```

Comment: thanks, @Chewie.  If x is blank (which *is* what occurs when extraction isn't allowed), that could also be due to a page being blank.  I guess if multiple blank pages are extracted to a list, though, that could be a sufficient test.

Comment: Yes, should probably have mentioned this is just a crude example. Depending on exactly what you do you might want to add a lot of fine tuning, and for the conflict with empty pages it might not even work, if you want an empty page to result in empty string being passed further into the program.